# Behavior different when "externalizing" certain config settings into external files

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webforms, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I have a legacy ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms application that's been in production for a while. I'm now adding additional functionality in the form of a WebAPI REST service to it.

Adding the WebAPI NuGet packages also added an entry into my `web.config` configuring the NewtonSoft.Json package runtime version:

Now, since I have my config "compartementalized", I wanted to put this into a separate `runtime.config` file and reference it from the main `web.config`:

```
<runtime configSource="runtime.config" />
```

When I do this, suddenly my registration of WebAPI routes in `global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ...

    // Route #1
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Route1", "test/{list}/{check}", new { Controller = "Devices" });
    ...
}
```

fails with an exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=the file or assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" or a dependency could not be found. 
>   Source=System.Net.Http.Formatting
>   FileName=Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed

To me, it seems as if the externalized `runtime.config` is not being read at the same time as the contents of the `web.config` itself...... which is rather surprising to me, I would have expected that the whole `web.config` including any "externalized" sub-config files would be read *before* any code in `global.asax.cs` is being executed...

Any insights? I don't even know where to go search for this level of detailed information on MSDN ....

Comment: Looks like you are not the first - http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Magnus-Rahl/Dates/2011/6/Todays-gotcha-configSource-on-the-runtime-section-element/  and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7552df69-d3a0-49e4-b45f-0fa4972fa64c/assembly-version-redirect-doesnt-work-with-a-configsource-in-runtime?forum=clr. Not sure if/where it covered on MSDN so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: if you add this as an answer, I'll happily accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web.config contains configuration info for a lot of different parts of the Windows web stack.

Some of it tells IIS what to do, some of it tells .NET what to do, some of it tells your application what to do. As such, different elements behave very differently depending on which part of the stack they target.

`<runtime>` is pretty low level, see [this from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kk0kk35(v=vs.100).aspx):

> "Runtime settings specify how the common language runtime handles
>   garbage collection and the version of an assembly to use in
>   configuration files."

`configSource="whatever"` is actually parsed by .NET itself, [see this from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource(v=vs.100).aspx):

> In ASP.NET applications, at run time you can assign to the
>   ConfigSource property the name of an alternative configuration file.

So basically .NET is run with the specified `<runtime>` settings before it will parse `configSource`.

If you play around with the web.config file in Visual Studio you will see that intellisense will tell you which attributes can go where.